# Java : How to handle POST request without form?

Tags: java, javascript, post, playframework

I'm sending a http post request from javascript, with some json data.

**Javascript**

```
var data = {text : "I neeed to store this string in database"}
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:9000/postJson"  , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(data);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    //Also, I've tried a jquery POST
    //$.post('postJson', {'data=' : JSON.stringify(data)});
    //But this doesn't make a request at all. What am I messing up here?
```

**Route**

```
POST    /postJson                   controllers.Application.postJson()
```

**Controller**

```
public static Result postJson(){

    //What should I write here to get the data

    //I've tried the below but values is showing null 
    RequestBody rb=request().body();
    final Map<String,String[]> values=rb.asFormUrlEncoded(); 

}
```

What is the way to parse the POST request body?
Much thanks!

Comment: Try to annotate the method `postJson` with `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)`

Comment: Try this : `DynamicForm requestData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();` and then you can use `requestData.get("key")` to get the values

Comment: Why are you sending JSON as a form?

Comment: Did the answer provide a solution? Did you, at least, check the code?

Answer (score 0):

Retreive the request body directly as JSON... no need to complicate your life.

```
public static Result postJson() {

    JsonNode rb = request().body().asJson();

    //manipulate the result
    String textForDBInsertion = rb.get("text").asText(); //retreives the value for the text key as String

    Logger.debug("text for insertion: " + textForDBInsertion
               + "JSON from request: " + rb);

    return ok(rb);
}
```

Also, I recommend you use the [AdvancedRestClient](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&ei=XnX3U5_kKojbavDugKgP&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&sig2=LknkTGWBdMxpUz53_8bS_A) Chrome plugin for testing. This way you can eliminate from the equation client-side code errors.

Cheers!